# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in chrome version 51.0.2704.84

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

getting the above error in the console since google chrome updated to version 51.0.2704.84 m this morning

seems to be coming from the line below in microsoftajax.js

```
this._originalTitle = document.title
```

Anyone getting this since the latest update?

Site still working fine in all browsers except chrome, and works fine in older version of chrome.

document.title in microsoftajax is equal to -

```
[Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at process (<anonymous>:80:133) at next (native) at Object._propertyDescriptors (<anonymous>:99:45) at next (native) at Object.getProperties (<anonymous>:69:132) at H.z._onPageRequestManagerBeginRequest (http://localhost:59138/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2:3:71226) at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:59138/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2:3:6758) at http://localhost:59138/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2:3:47047 at Function.H.w.raiseEvent (http://localhost:59138/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2:3:25458) at _onFormSubmit (http://localhost:59138/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2:9:23310)]
```

Comment: *"seems to be coming from the line below"* That's exceedingly unlikely, I recommend debugging further. For instance: Use the powerful debugger built into Chrome to put a breakpoint on that line, and see if it's **really** breaking there.

Comment: Using the chrome debugger, it breaks, and the page reloads when it hits the line I said, in this function of microsoftajax.js.


z._onPageRequestManagerBeginRequest = function() {
            this._ignoreTimer = c;
            this._originalTitle = document.title
        }

document.title in this case is an exception - I've posted that exception in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Interesting one, turns out that something recently changed in chrome has broken img tags with an id of "title". This will replace and break the window.document.title of the page.

Easy to test yourself with a one line html page.

Comment: What's (probably) happening is that Chrome, for some reason, takes IDs of elements and turns them into "global" variables.  So, maybe you're accessing the element instead of what you expected... without realizing it.

Comment: This is my current guess, and I'm still doing some looking into it, but regardless this worked up until my chrome updated yesterday afternoon - it has the potential to affect many currently running sites, from what I can tell (though I'm not certain naming anything "title" is a great idea myself)